# Can you add a border around your current line in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

So basically I would like to know if I can make my current line in Visual Studio Code have a border like it does in Visual Studio 2017.

[image: The top image is how it looks like now and the bottom is how I would like it to look]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#ffffff70"
}
```

Comment: Wow, I've spent so much time looking for it and couldn't find anything. Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you because it was buried too deep here -> [Theme Color | Visual Studio Code Extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color)  and it is always great to get extra help on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hey, I wanted to make my outline opaque and thanks to your method I've achieved it so quickly. If anyone stumbles upon this thread and want the same just change the `#ffffff70` value to `#0000`